# How to measure response time to different endpoints from different AWS regions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, latency, availability-zone, aws-regions

Let's supposed I am running an API that are available via different endpoints, each being deploy in different data centres. For instance:

- `ny.api.example.com` (New York, US data centre)
- `ln.api.example.com` (London, UK data centre)
- `sg.api.example.com` (Singapore data centre)

I want to use a service like [Cedexis Openmix](https://www.cedexis.com/openmix/) to point DNS requests for `api.example.com` to the endpoint that would provide the quickest response time. (E.g. a request from Paris would resolve to `ln.api.example.com`) Therefore, I need some data about the latency of requests to each endpoint.

Most of the traffic to our API will be from other enterprise applications, and so are likely to originate from major AWS data centres. So **is there a service that measures the response time / latency *from* different AWS regions / availability zones *to* different endpoints**?

---

There are several services that measures latency *from* my browser to different AWS availability zones, such as [CloudHarmony](https://cloudharmony.com/speedtest-for-aws), [CloudPing](https://www.cloudping.info/) and [CloudWatch](http://www.cloudwatch.in/). I am looking for something similar, but the other way round - *from* AWS availability zones *to* a specific endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

You could use AWS route53 health check to your end point. Or you could predict the latency between to aws regions from https://www.cloudping.co/